# hasta 10 enteros antes del punto decimal con expresion regular

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

Como puedo hacer una expresion regular que acepte hasta 10 enteros un punto y hasta 10 decimales, tengo la siguiente expresion regular, pero no funciona solo funciona con los decimales

```
/^([0-9]{0,10})+\.?[0-9]{0,10})$/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hola puedes usar esta expresión regular:

```
/^(\d{1,10})(\.\d{1,10})?$/
```

\d es equivalente a [0-9]

Voy a explicar la expresión que consta de dos partes.

```
^(\d{1,10})
```

Con la expresión de arriba le estamos diciendo que acepte de 1 a 10 números al inicio de la cadena

```
(\.\d{1,10})?$
```

Con la expresión de arriba le estamos diciendo que acepte un punto seguido de 1 a 10 números y con el signo de interrogación le estamos diciendo que puede o no venir lo que tenemos dentro de los paréntesis, finalmente con el signo de $ le indicamos que es el final de nuestra cadena.

Para probar las expresiones regulares te recomiendo [está](https://regexr.com/) página soporta JavaScript & PHP/PCRE RegEx, para probar la expresión regular ponla de la siguiente forma:

```
^(\d{1,10})(\.\d{1,10})?$
```

Y en donde dice texto ingresa los números para probar.

Comment: Hola Sergio. `[\.]` es redundante. El punto no es necesario escaparlo dentro de las clases. Normalmente o bien utilizas `\.` o `[.]`, pero ambas cosas es raro. Lo mismo pasa para `[\d]`. Se puede poner `\d` directamente.

Comment: Tienes razón, ya actualice la respuesta y parece mas "limpia" la expresión regular, saludos.

Comment: @SergioLópez hay cifras que son de miles y son separadas por una coma pero esta expresion no reconoce la coma al separar las cifras en miles (3 en 3 a la derecha del punto decimal) que puedo hacer?